# How to change Instance name in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, connection, database-connection

Is it posible to change instance name in SQL SERVER? Now I have `./MSSQLR2` and
I would like `./SQLEXPRESS`. I was trying to do this through this commands

```
--sp_dropserver 'HYDROGEN\MSSQLR2';
--sp_addserver 'HYDROGEN\MSSQLR2', local;
```

and then restart server, but It seems not work.

Comment: What's the business value for you to change instance name? It seldom affects application or design.

Comment: One reason is when everyone else on a team has their instance set one way, and yours is another, there is thrashing of changes to the connection string between code check-ins.  It further makes me appreciate the previous job where we had a dedicated SQL development server.  (Minimize differences in environments.)

Answer (score 5):

For future reference, `sp_dropserver` and `sp_addserver`  can only be used  to rename the part of the instance name that corresponds to the computer name. So you could use it to rename your server name `HYDROGEN` to `HELIUM`, but you can't change the instance name `MSQSQLR2` without reinstalling (see Jerome Bradley's answer). For details can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx).

```
sp_dropserver 'HYDROGEN\MSSQLR2';
GO
sp_addserver 'HELIUM\MSSQLR2', local;
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create instance aliases:
http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1620

Comment: You *can*, but I don't think you *should*. See [this answer from Remus](http://stackoverflow.com/a/908205/61305).

Comment: The referenced "answer from Remus" has been removed as of at least Dec 2014.

Comment: I couldn't, it didn't work.